# Zend_Db -> update() increments my values twice?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a pretty weird problem related to zend framework's zend_db.

I use

```
$this -> update(array('visits' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`visits` + 1')), new Zend_Db_Expr("`ip` = '{$ip}' AND `day` = {$day} AND `month` = {$month} AND `year` = {$year}"));
```

to increments `visits` with 1. The problem is that Zend increments it with value * 2, in this case 2, if I say `visits` + 5, it then increments with 10?!!

It is really strange, since the pure SQL works. I've tried going to the code of the Update() function, then I just say `exit($sql)` and I can see that the SQL is ok, it runs properly under phpMyAdmin, except when I let update() run.

I thought I might call update() twice somewhere, so I've put exit(); in it, so it would break after running once... same problem...

Thanks in advance!

Btw, my zend framework is 1.11.11 or less.

Comment: Log all mysql queries and verify that it's running twice. Then try to track it down in the code.

Comment: Is it possible that the browser request to favicon.ico is causing the update to run a second time? Easiest way to test this would be to error_log($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) when you do the query, or add a favicon to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes Tim, that was exactly the problem. What's interesting though is that Chrome looks for favicon even if I didn't declare one in the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens if you write it as a standard sql update, without the zend_db_table's update() function? does it work as expected ?

```
$this->_db->query('UPDATE ' . $this->_name . ' SET visits = visits + 1 WHERE ip = ? AND `day` = ? AND `month` = ? AND `year` = ?", array($ip, $year, $month, $day);
```

If it does work correctly, it means there's something wrong with the update() function.
If it's still an issue, you might running the script twice somehow.

Also, does your class extend directly from `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`? I had some cases that the update function was override with a different logic.

Comment: It is in fact running twice. I have some tremendeous issue with my apache configuration.